# PDFBox Add Validation Information on Certification Signature

Tags: java, pdfbox

how to add validation information on PDF during signing if signature use Certification

```
SigUtils.setMDPPermission(doc, signature, 1);
```

cause warning message on function tell `addValidationInformation.validateSignature(inPath, outFile)` :

```
PDF is certified to forbid changes, some readers may report the document as invalid despite that the PDF specification allows DSS additions
```

i call `addValidationInformation` function after signing doc, `signing.signPDF()`;

what i have tried with this function :

```
private void makeLTV() {
        try {
            COSDictionary catalogDict = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
            catalogDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
            byte[][] certs = new byte[certificateChain.length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < certificateChain.length; i++) {
                certs[i] = certificateChain[i].getEncoded();
            }
            // Assign byte array for storing certificate in DSS Store.
            List<CRL> crlList = new ArrayList<CRL>();
            List<OCSPResp> ocspList = new ArrayList<OCSPResp>();
            for (int i = 0; i < certificateChain.length; i++) {
                X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateChain[i];
                if (!cert.getIssuerDN().equals(cert.getSubjectDN())) {
                    X509Certificate issuerCert = (X509Certificate) certificateChain[i + 1];
                    if (issuerCert != null) {
                        OCSPResp ocspResp;
                        ocspResp = new GetOcspResp().getOcspResp(cert, issuerCert);
                        if (ocspResp != null) {
                            ocspList.add(ocspResp);
                        }
                    }

                    crlList.addAll(new DssHelper().readCRLsFromCert(cert));
                }
            }
            byte[][] crls = new byte[crlList.size()][];
            for (int i = 0; i < crlList.size(); i++) {
                crls[i] = ((X509CRL) crlList.get(i)).getEncoded();
                LogSystem.info("set CRL data");
            }
            byte[][] ocsps = new byte[ocspList.size()][];
            for (int i = 0; i < ocspList.size(); i++) {
                ocsps[i] = ocspList.get(i).getEncoded();
            }
            Iterable<byte[]> certifiates = Arrays.asList(certs);
            COSDictionary dss = new DssHelper().createDssDictionary(certifiates, Arrays.asList(crls),
                    Arrays.asList(ocsps));
            catalogDict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"), dss);

  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            LogSystem.error(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

before  `doc.addSignature(signature, signatureInterface, signatureOptions);`

Comment: What is the validation model applicable for your signature? And which validators shall be able to make use of the validation data you add?

Comment: both of them not working with my signature, addvalidationsignature give me broken pdf signature, makeltv not contain any validation

Comment: What is the validation model applicable for your signature? And which validators shall be able to make use of the validation data you add? And please share an example signature to see why adding LTV fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PDF is certified to forbid changes, some readers may report the document as invalid despite that the PDF specification allows DSS additions

Well, the LTV level addition is indeed allowed to PDF documents even with restricted MDP permissions. See "Table 257 — Entries in the DocMDP transform parameters dictionary" of ISO 32000-2:

> **P number (Optional)** The access permissions granted for this document. **Changes to a PDF that are incremental updates which include only the data necessary to add DSS’s 12.8.4.3**, "Document Security Store (DSS)" **and/or document timestamps 12.8.5**, "Document timestamp (DTS) dictionary" to the document **shall not be considered as changes** to the document as defined in the choices below.

So technically speaking you are allowed to add validation data to a PDF signature.
However, you need to take into account the practical aspect of this change. For example, the most commonly used application for reading electronic signatures Adobe, more likely, will invalidate such change. The problem here, that the "extension" of a signature with a validation data and/or a timestamp may involve other changes within a PDF document, which may be not considered as part of the allowed changes, as there is no formal guidance on either how to create such signature nor as validate them.

For your information, ETSI standardization group is currently working on a new set of standards that should provide a formal guidance for validation of different AdES signature formats. So maybe in the future this part will be clarified.

For the implementation part of the LTV level addition, I would recommend to add validation data to your signature after the production time of a first timestamp (signature-time-stamp or a PDF document timestamp), that will ensure that the revocation data is fresh and can be considered during the validation process (see "5.2.5 Revocation freshness checker" of [EN 319 102-1](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319100_319199/31910201/01.03.01_60/en_31910201v010301p.pdf)).
For this you will need to add the revocation data to a signed document within a new incremental update (revision). For this you will need to use the method

```
pdDocument.saveIncremental(...)
```

executed on a signed PDDocument.

Comment: *"The problem here, that the "extension" of a signature with a validation data and/or a timestamp may involve other changes within a PDF document, which may be not considered as part of the allowed changes"* - at the beginning of this year I did some tests. Adobe Acrobat did not accept any incremental updates to P=1 files even if the change clearly was only adding a DSS. Even adding an empty incremental update was rejected. And this happened independent of the PDF version and of the presence of a developer extension. Thus, the PDF the OP saw is there for a reason.

Comment: I find Adobe Acrobat is too strict in this matter. I do not think its validation process is dependent on a PDF document version and/or takes the extension dictionary into account at all. But indeed as its the most commonly used tool, it is quite important to have an implementation aligned with (not always 100% right) Adobe's validation. Therefore OP needs to decide which direction to choose.

Comment: *"I find Adobe Acrobat is too strict in this matter"* - well, not only "too strict" but simply wrong. At least in case of PDF-2 documents or PDF-1.7 documents with the appropriate developer extension this strictness is a bug.

Comment: Arg, I just re-read my first comment. The last sentence should have been: "Thus, the _warning_ the OP saw is there for a reason."